# How to set up `cluster.schedulingPolicy` in Node.js 18?

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, environment-variables

I am trying to run the [`loadtest`](https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest) module in cluster mode so it takes advantage of multiple cores. For the included test server it runs more efficiently using the `cluster.schedulingPolicy` of `cluster.SCHED_NONE` instead of the default round-robin `cluster.SCHED_RR`:

```
$ NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY='none' node bin/testserver.js
```

I would prefer to set it up in code. The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#clusterschedulingpolicy) says that I have to set it up in code:

```
cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_NONE
```

This works fine with old-style `require()`, but there is a problem when using modern `import`:

```
import * as cluster from 'cluster'
cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_NONE
```

It yields an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'schedulingPolicy' of object '[object Module]'
```

I have also tried importing just the variable:

```
import {schedulingPolicy} from 'cluster'
```

But this does not work. Setting the environment variable in code doesn't either:

```
process.env['NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY'] = cluster.SCHED_NONE
```

It seems to change the value but then the children don't receive cluster.SCHED_NONE but cluster.SCHED_RR.

So, how am I supposed to set the `schedulingPolicy` other than with an environment variable set from outside Node.js?

Searching for an answer here has yielded no valid results, all were using `require()`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nasty workaround: since `import`s are always hoisted to the top of the file, setting the env variable before the `import` does not work. But if set the env variable and use a dynamic import afterwards, it works as expected. Short snippet showing the behaviour:

```
process.env.NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY = 'none'
//import * as cluster from 'cluster'
const cluster = await import('cluster')

if (cluster.isPrimary) { 
    console.log(`process.env.NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY: ${process.env.NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY}`)
    for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) { 
        cluster.fork()
        setTimeout(() => console.log(`cluster.schedulingPolicy: ${cluster.schedulingPolicy}`), 1000)
    } 
} else { 
    setTimeout(() => null, 1000)
}
```

The issue has been reported to [the Node.js core](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/49240).